# Plugin using Eigen crashes the second time it's run

Tags: c++, gcc, crash, eigen, gcc4.9

I'm writing a module which is loaded by a program to add functionality, and I've stumbled upon a really weird crash which I can't understand.

First of all, I've compiled the exact same thing in Windows using MSVS2015, where it works without any problems. However, when I compile it using GCC 4.9.3 on Unix (Solaris 10), the session crashes the second time the code is run, and I've managed to narrow it down to more or less exactly what it is that crashes it: copying Eigen::MatrixXf objects.

A very simple example which makes it crash is the following:

```
void entry()
{
    // Initialize matrix1
    Eigen::MatrixXf test(3, 3);

    // Fill it with 3x3 values.
    test << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;

    // Initialize matrix2
    Eigen::MatrixXf test2(3, 3);

    // Copy
    test2 = test;
}
```

However, everything that doesn't involve copying matrices seems to work perfectly fine, and when I build a very simple executable program, I can copy arrays fine.

I've managed to narrow down the arguments in my Makefile, but there's no difference:

```
CC_FLAGS = -I$(INC) -fPIC
LINK_FLAGS = -shared
```

I'm really out of ideas as to what could be the cause for this, so I'm hoping someone will be able to point me in the right direction. I'm quite new to Unix development and not sure what the best way to debug this would be, so help there is also appreciated.

Worth to note is that I had to build the version of gcc used myself since there was no official binary for Solaris 10 (x86), but there were no errors and it works very well for everything other than this.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Eigen?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. It's the latest stable version: 3.2.8.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with gcc 4.9.2 on Ubuntu. Can you create a [MCVE]?

Comment: I tried it just now, and I can't get it to crash by importing it in a simple application with only a main function, so I'm guessing it is related to the program which imports it then (which is a proprietary program within fin tech), but I don't see how that could be possible? Is it possible that some features aren't possible to use when the library is imported by another program that was compiled by an older version?

Comment: It is most probably an alignment issue. What is you compile with `-DEIGEN_MALLOC_ALREADY_ALIGNED=0`? If that does not help, please add the backtrace.

Comment: EIGEN_MALLOC_ALREADY_ALIGNED=0 did not help. I'm not sure how I should generate a backtrace (I guess attaching gdb should do it if it's compiled with -g?), but I'll try to figure it out and attach the backtrace here.

Comment: For some reason, I can't manage to get a backtrace with symbols. I'm compiling with -g, but when I debug the process with gdb, "info sharedlibrary" returns "No shared libraries loaded at this time.".

Comment: Temporarily gave up on getting symbols into GDB, and tried to compile with -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE, and it doesn't crash now. Does this make any more sense?

Also, what's the performance difference I can expect without vectorization? I'm only doing matrix multiplication and cholesky decompositions, as well as a lot of random accesses.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough, compiling with optimization (-O2/-O3) solved this issue.